# How to add a non-existant column to a sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cart

I have a little problem. I'm looking for a way to "add" a column to a sql query.

Actually I sort some product from a table with this order:

```
@prod = Table.find(:all,{:select=>["id, prod-id, cost"],:conditions=>["something = ? and somethingelse = ?","that thing","that other thing"],:order=>"id DESC"})
```

Then I put the result of this query into a Table (html) with a form to add the product into a Cart.

The problem comes now. In my Cart the product are like that:

```
cart: #<Cart:0x00000005ce0a68 @items=[[#<Table id: 6024, prod-id: 907509, cost: 33>]]>
```

And I need to add a "column" to the data in my cart. To get my Cart like that:

```
cart: #<Cart:0x00000005ce0a68 @items=[[#<Table id: 6024, prod-id: 907509, cost: 33, quantity: 1>]]>
```

Here is my Cart:

```
class Cart
      attr_reader :items

      def initialize
        @items = []
        @total_price = 0
      end

      def add_product(product)
        @items << product
        product
      end

      def total_price
        @items.sum{ |item| item.prod_pxuttc}
      end

      def total_items
        @items.length
      end
    end
```

I need to not-add any Column to my Table. Because I will have to import data from another Source Database into my Table, and I can't change the Source Database. *(Yes it's a stupid process, but that's what my Customer want)*

I have totaly no idea about how to give name to the process I need to do.

---

**[edit]**

I found a way to resolve my problem.
By creating a second table, with the same column plus column quantity, with a default empty row.
Then I select my product from First Table, the default row from the Second Table, and I put value from product into the variable of the default row. Then I put my new variable into my Cart.

It's a bit tricky but it works.

Comment: I think you need an items table, and a has_many :items in the Cart model... supposing your cart is a model; or is it just in session?

Comment: the cart is stored into a session it's not a Table.

Comment: So: what is your problem? Does not your Cart class work? what errors do you have?

Comment: I need to have a column "quantity" in my cart, but this column doesn't exist on the Table where I take my product.

And I need to get the Column without adding it to the Table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe define Cart as the following will solve the problem.

```
class Product
  attr_accessor quantity
end

class Cart
  ...
end
```

Comment: I need to add the column Quantity to my Cart, Without adding the column to the Table. That's all the matter.
(the cart isn't into a table, it's a session stored model)

Comment: But type of @item is Product. I think Product is the model of a table. Could you add quantity column to product?

Comment: It's a bit complicate. I have to keep the table like it is at the moment, because I will have to import data into the table from another database. And this other database won't have the new column and I can't add this new column to the Source Database.

That's why I need to do that without adding any column to my Table.

Comment: I thought two ways. Maybe they are answers.

Comment: I think the answer is when I put my product into my Cart. Here is what I put into my cart:
 `product = Table.find(:first,{:select=>["id, prod-id, cost"],:conditions=>["id = ?","#{params[:prod_to_add]}"],:order=>"prod-id DESC"})`.
Then I do `@cart.add_product(product)`. Which do `@items << product`

I don't know how to give the ":quantity => 1" to this process.

Comment: Please try the newest answer.

Comment: heum, I don't want to add a quantity to the Cart. but to the Product.

I select `id, prod-id, cost` from my table. And I need to put `id, prod-id, cost, quantity` into my cart. To be able to change the quantity of each product of the cart.

Comment: Then you maybe add quantity attribute to Product above Cart, just like the newest answer.

Comment: I found a way to do what I was needing.

I created a second table, which has the "quantity" column, then I select one row from table 1, and a default row from table 2, put value from the row of table 1 into the variable that contain the row from the table 2.